# qemu-system-arm run barebox image

Tags: yocto, qemu, barebox

may I ask? I need to build a barebox image inside yocto and run it in qemu, I can’t build a qemuarm image in yocto, there is no such recipe, in general, the question is, is it possible to somehow slip under such a dts into the barebox assembly that qemu-system-arm with `-M mcimx6ul-evk` option will be able to run barebox builded in yocto?

Comment: You can set `MACHINE = "qemuarm`. What image you build is irrelevant.

Comment: qemuarm does not allow to build barebox recipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable `CONFIG_BOARD_ARM_GENERIC_DT=y` in the barebox config and barebox will generate an `images/barebox-dt-2nd.img` file that is bootable like a Linux kernel: You can pass it to QEMU `-kernel` and it will receive a device tree from the outside.

barebox contains a `test/emulate.pl` script that can spawn QEMU VMs for you. Passing it `--dryrun` will print the options used (edited for formatting):

```
$ ./test/emulate.pl --no-tuxmake --dry-run virt@vexpress_defconfig
/usr/bin/qemu-system-arm -M virt -cpu cortex-a7 -m 1024M -kernel \
   ./build/images/barebox-dt-2nd.img -serial mon:stdio -trace file=/dev/null
```

In the above case, QEMU will provide the device tree, but you can pass your own as well (make sure to build barebox with a config that enables board and platform support in line with the FDT and QEMU machine you configure). See the barebox documentation on [Emulated targets](https://www.barebox.org/doc/latest/boards/emulated.html) for more information.

Comment: what -machine and -cpu option i should use in qemu? thank you for answer

Comment: @IvanIvanovich Shouldn't it be the other way round? You have some hardware, that you configure bootloader and kernel to work with it. If you just want to try out barebox, the QEMU Virt machine works well. I've amended the answer.